# PHP $_POST username sanitation - how that this is not ok

Tags: php, post, validation, sanitize, alphanumeric

I've googled and searched SO and everything, but I can't come to an answer.

Why is the PHP code below letting plus sign through:

```
$aValid = array('-', '_', '.');

if (ctype_alnum(str_replace($aValid, '', $_POST['Rusername']))){
```

(If user types 1234+ it goes on like it vas valid????).

I, normally, found a bypass, but is it really necessary;

```
$aValid = array('-', '_', '.'); 
if (ctype_alnum(str_replace($aValid, '', (htmlentities ( trim ( $_POST['Rusername'] ) , ENT_NOQUOTES ))))){
    echo "+ ok";
}else{
    echo "+ not ok";
}
```

I would like to use this kind of validation and just add special chars to $aValid when needed.

Before inserting to MySQL I would do mysql_real_escape_string or prepared statements.

Any ideas why the + sign is ok for first piece of code. In my opinion it really should't be.

Latest update - I needed few hours of low-level debugging HTTP headers to figure iz out that my A side changed the Content-Type so that the + sign became space before it got to PHP if clause (alowed in my whitelist)...

What an - I hope it will never happen to you - experience :)

Reminder to myself: jQuery should be mentioned if it was such a major player in this validation process...

Comment: `In the standard C locale letters are just [A-Za-z].`, maybe you don't use the standard C locale.

Comment: True, I wan't to use UTF-8 to allow different characters. Obviously there is my error. Will investigate. 

Just one more thing: I tried with this and it also accepts + sign as valid;

`code`if (!preg_match('/^[a-žA-Ž-_ ]++$/', $_POST['Rime'])) {`code`

Answer (score 2):

What you should do is inspect each stage of the process, rather than slamming them all into a single line:

```
$name = $_POST['Rusername'];
var_dump($name);
$name = str_replace($aValid, '', $name);
var_dump($name);
```

etc... Basic debugging. If you've got multiple stages in a statement, then check each individual stage. ctype may be working perfectly fine, but the str_replace is failing you somehow.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try with this and see what I get.

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas why the + sign is ok for first piece of code. In my opinion it really should't be.

It's not ok... the first piece of code return false..

If you want to remove the `+` sign you have to add it into the `$aValid` variable

Comment: Sorry, you are not correct on this one. $aValid is for allowed characters, so that it "upgrades" the ctype_alnum